# Why isn't my grid-container positioning the grid-cells the way I want it to?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 10%);
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: white;
}

.grid-container > div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #B10DC9;
}

.grid-container > div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.grid-container > div:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

GC = grid-container.
GI = grid-item.

So far I can add in any number of GIs into the GC and have each GI take up only 10% of the GC's `width`. Is there a way to make it so that for any number of GIs I add, each GI takes up an equal portion of the GC - achieving this through CSS (not javascript)? `fr` units did not do the trick.

Comment: First, tell me if you need to transfer your divas under each other?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov How you had it in your first link (each cell takes up 1/3rd of the width of the container) was right

Comment: Hi Toni, editing to ask a different question is a big no-no here on SO. Try not to do that again :). Just update the question with a note that you've solved it and how you did it, and go make a new question.

Comment: Apparently `repeat(auto-fit, 1fr)` isn't valid. But `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(1px, 1fr))` is valid and does something very similar to what's intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set 10%, which means that your divs will not creep out to the entire free width.

But you can do it like this using `minmax()`:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
```

This means that when your divs reach `100px` wide, these divs will blend under each other.

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: white;
}

.grid-container > div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #B10DC9;
}

.grid-container > div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.grid-container > div:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> fr units did not do the trick.

Use it correctly and it will do it:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr; /* all columns eqaul to each other */
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* use a column flow */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid-container>div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #B10DC9;
}

.grid-container>div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.grid-container>div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div>1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif. Would you say your solution is more common/better? If so, why?

Comment: @tonitone120 I wouldn't say better but probably closer to your use case since (1) I will always have a column layout, no wrapping here (2) all item will be equal with no min width boundary